# Flutter force screen update with initState

Tags: flutter

I have a StatefulWidget in which I load data from the server using the initState(). It is somethig like this:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    // ... Load the data
  }

  // build
}
```

When I use the Navigator.pop() or Navigator.pushNamed() it does not reinit the state. Is there any away to prevent this?

Comment: You can just call 'setState(() {});' after 'pop()'.

Comment: and in the pushNamed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call 'pushNamed' in MyApp, wait until  'pushNamed()' will be returned which is occurred when 'pop()' is called.
After that, refresh data and call build() by calling 'setState()'.

```
await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/somePage");

...
[call reloadData sentence]
...

setState(() {});
```